# Django login with custom form template

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm using the Django authentication with my login form in my template, after i pressed the login button on the form the page refreshed but doesn't log me in and doesn't show the {{context}} error in the template.

My view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        all_categories = Categories.objects.all()
        all_websites = Website.objects.all()
        all_discounts = Discount.objects.order_by('-id')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/',categories=all_categories,websites=all_websites,discounts=all_discounts)
        else:
            context = 'wrong username or password'
            all_categories = Categories.objects.all()
            all_websites = Website.objects.all()
            all_discounts = Discount.objects.order_by('-id')
            return redirect('/',categories=all_categories,websites=all_websites,discounts=all_discounts,context=context)
```

My form (header.html)

```
<div class="col-md-3 top-info-cart text-right mt-lg-4">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}.</p>
                        <p><a href="{% url 'frontend:logout' %}">logout</a></p>
                    {% else %}
                        <ul class="cart-inner-info">
                        <li class="button-log">
                            <a class="btn-open" href="#">
                                <span class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>{{context}}</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    <!---->
                    <div class="overlay-login text-left">
                        <button type="button" class="overlay-close1">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="wrap">
                            <h5 class="text-center mb-4">Login Now</h5>
                            <div class="login p-5 bg-dark mx-auto mw-100">
                                <form action="{% url 'frontend:login' %}" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="mb-2">User name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your informations with anyone else.</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="mb-2">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"type="password">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit mb-4" value="Login">Sign In</button>
                                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'frontend:signup' %}" style="color: orange;">SIGN UP </a></p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And my urls.py:

```
from  django.urls import path
from .import views
app_name = 'frontend'
urlpatterns = [
    #index
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
     #/discount/id
    path('<id>/',views.single,name='single'),
    #/category/category_name
    path('category/<name>',views.category,name='category'),
    #/signup
    path('signup',views.signup,name='signup'),
    #/logout
    path('logout',views.logout,name='logout'),
    #/login
    path('login',views.login_view,name='login')
]
```

It's because of my authentication is wrong or my view function ? i been trying to fix this but still haven't figure it out. Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: I would suggest you to use breakpoint(python3) or pdb(Python2) to stop the execution at user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password) and explore on whats happening!

Comment: im fairly new to Django so it's import import pdb; pdb.set_trace() and breakpoint() after authentication ? cause i cant connect to the website after i added it

Comment: yes. Once you have applied that statements, the control will stop at that location. Later use https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/ to understand how u need to debug